# Is there a way to run feature files in parallel using cucumber-js v5.1.0?

Tags: cucumberjs

There is currently a --parallel option that can run scenarios in parallel using cucumberjs 5.1.0. I want to find out if there is a way to run feature files in parallel instead of scenarios, with this version of cucumberjs.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it looks like there is only the capability to run by scenario https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/src/runtime/parallel/master.js#L105 . What is your reason for wanting to run by Feature instead of scenario?

Comment: Thanks. The reason is I don't want scenarios in the same feature file to get executed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A scenario is meant to be a completely independent test that don't rely on anything set up by the scenarios that ran before it, which is why the makers of cucumber have provided parallel functionality in the way that they have.

Hooks can be used to set up the scenarios individually (by tags or the scenario's name) or run scripts to register users and other test data needed for the tests.

In summary, the way they provide the parallel testing functionality means you are forced to stick to best practices.